# Multi matches character in RegExp alway end at last one

Tags: javascript, regex

> Hello everyone, I'm a stackoverflow novice.
>
> If I have any wrong about asking this question, hope to redress me.
>   :)

If my test string is `'One\nTwo\n\nFour'`,

I use the RegExp `/(.)*\n/` in JavaScript,

will match `'One\nTwo\n\n'` not `'One\n', 'Two\n' and '\n'` in my expectation.

And I want to get the result is `'One', 'Two', '' and 'Four'`.

---

Very thanks @Dalorzo's answer.

`'One\nTwo\n\nFour'.split(/\n/g) //outputs ["One", "Two", "", "Four"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe better could be a split to achieve the same goal? by

With **Regex**:

```
'One\nTwo\n\nFour'.split(/\n/) //outputs ["One", "Two", "", "Four"]
```

or *without* **Regex** like:

```
'One\nTwo\n\nFour'.split('\n') //outputs ["One", "Two", "", "Four"]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(.*?)(?:\n|$)
```

Make your greedy search non greedy.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/30

```
var re = /(.*?)(?:\n|$)/g;
var str = 'One\nTwo\n\nFour';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: This approach works because you put the `*` inside the group and used the `g` flag to iterate over all the matches of group #1.  Whether you use `(.*)` or `(.*?)`, it has to consume everything before the next occurrence of `(?:\n|$)`; greediness is irrelevant.